# Slider revolution is not showing up on my wordpress pages just white space

Tags: wordpress, slider, slider-revolution

I am using WordPress 6.4.3, and I am utilizing a free trial of Slider Revolution 6.6.8. I also installed the latest version, 6.6.20. However, the issue is that the slider is not showing up on the pages; instead, there's just a white space in that area. Additionally and i am using translogic theme, I inspected the error on the console:

```
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.4.1:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.4.1
(index):797 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'revolutionInit')
 at Object.init ((index):797:10)
 at window.RS_MODULES.callSliders (rs6.min.js?ver=6.6.20:1:128757)
 at window.RS_MODULES.checkMinimal (rs6.min.js?ver=6.6.20:1:129709)
 at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):855:69)
```

anyone please help me i am in really trouble.
 `my site link: https://techshippers.com/`

I just want to resolve the slider issue. I want it to show up on all pages where I have placed it